# Custom viewgroup with predefined view is not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, parameters, constraints

I'm using the following code:

```
class TestConstraintLayout(context: Context): ConstraintLayout(context) {
    private val simpleConstraintSet = SimpleConstraintSet(this)

    private val textView = AppCompatTextView(context)

    init {
        textView.id = View.generateViewId()
        textView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            10,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )

        textView.setBackgroundColor(-10000)

        simpleConstraintSet.build {
            textView leftToLeftOf parent
            textView topToTopOf parent
            textView rightToRightOf parent
            textView bottomToBottomOf parent

            textView withHorizontalBiasOf 0.3f
        }

        addView(textView)
    }

}
```

And despite the horizontal bias i get the following result:

[image]

Everything works perfectly outside of my custom layout, so i suppose this isn't the way to set whether the layoutparams or the constraints inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake, i should have added the textView with addView before the constraints and params.